# Best aproach for working with Time in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm trying to make a field where user will enter amount of time per day he/she spent on a project per day. It can be from 30 minutes to 8 hours. Is `DateTimePicker` with `CustomFormat` hh:mm best choice for this? Or there's better alternative for WinForms C#? Maybe `TextBox` or `MaskedTextBox` with special settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the MaskedTextBox is generally a pain, this is a situation it could be useful. With Mask="00:00".
Give it a spin.

And you will have to convert to/from text to TimeSpan yourself

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with it, I would build a custom control for this. Maybe a read only textbox where I display the formatted time spent, and 2 buttons, one for up, one for down that looked something like the old VB updown control. I'd suggest adding a minimum, maximum, and up / down interval properties also. This should be an easy enough control to do and it would go a long way towards simplifying the user input.

Comment: I have no idea how to build custom controls :(

Comment: @MadBoy - It is not hard, here is a simple custom control tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cutebutton.aspx. Have a look at it. Basically I am suggesting you combine several standard controls into one, add a few custom properties and enable you users to click an up button to add time in say 15 minute increments.

Comment: Will give it a go when project is a bit more advanced. Right now i need to do it quickly, later on i'll tune things up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a textfield with the format "7h 30m"  (7 hours and 30 minutes)

Comment: I would like it to be Localized and used with ease by users, with low or even none possibility for error.